# how to convert the foreign key to value

Tags: python, django

I want to query a table with foreign key. Is it possible to replace the foreign key to its value and convert it to dictionary?

```
Model.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)


Views.py
    dic = {}
    dic["data"] = list(Item.objects.all().values())
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want `data` to be? an `Item` or a `Category`? Where does the `ForeignKey` come into play?

Comment: `Item.objects.all().values('name', 'category_id')` or `Item.objects.all().values('name', 'category__id')`

Comment: As Klaus says, you could even do `Item.objects.all().values('name', 'category__name')` to get the name value.

Comment: I was also a new member and learning Django. Multiple downvotes really demotivated me and impacted my learning skills. Being experienced does not mean discourage others. Though formation of question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are looking for. But I understand that you need a result where instead of ID you get the name of category.
There are two approach. First and better is to change your models as:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.name)
```

This is a better method using this you do not have add an extra line requesting name of category each time.
Another is to query in this manner:

```
Item.objects.all().values('name', 'category__id')
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Your right, instead of the ID, I want to get the name of category or any attribute of the foreign ID. The second approach was working for me but the first one still returns the given id.

Comment: Can you give your views.py using first approach.

Comment: Same as my views.py above. If I understand it correctly, when I use the first approach and use `Item.objects.all().values()` with out parameter, it will automatically change the category_id to its name?

Comment: Yes it will automatically change. Basically anytime you call category model without specifying column, it will give the name.